# How to programmatically create a new KB article in Dynamics CRM 2013?

Tags: sdk, dynamics-crm-online, article

I am trying to set up an integration using the SDK to create KB article records in CRM 2013, and so far haven't been able to figure out a good way to build the article xml.  We want to use sharepoint as our document authoring tool , and then send those documents over to CRM.  From the research I've done so far, I know that in order to create a new kb article I need to link it to a template.  I created a very basic template with one section as a test to work with, then in a test app using the SDK I created a new KBArticle entity instance, set the necessary required fields and assigned the template to the new article.  I tried building the xml for the ArticleXML attribute by starting with the StructureXML attribute of the template and filling in the content section with some test html content.  I was able to create the kb article successfully and then load it up in CRM, but it doesn't look right yet.  I also created a new kb article through the UI and then using the SDK I retrieved it and examined  the ArticleXML attribute to compare with the one I'm trying to create programmatically.

Here's the basic structure of the ArticleXML for an article created in the UI:

```
<articledata>
   <section id="0">
      <content>
         <![CDATA[<b>Article content located here</b>]]>
      </content>
   </section>
   <section id="1">
      <content>
         <![CDATA[]]>
      </content>
   </section>
</articledata>
```

Now here is the StructureXML attribute value from the template I created:

```
<kbarticle>
   <sections nextSectionId="1">
      <section type="docprop" name="title"/>
      <section type="docprop" name="number"/>
      <section type="edit" id="0">
         <![CDATA[Content]]>
         <instructions>
            <![CDATA[Place KB article content here]]>
         /instructions>
      </section>
   </sections>
   <stylesheet>
      <article>
         <style name="background-color" value="#ffffff"/>
         <style name="font-family" value="verdana"/>
         <style name="font-size" value="10pt"/>
      </article>
      <title>
         <style name="font-family" value="verdana"/>
         <style name="font-size" value="16pt"/>
      </title>
      <number>
         <style name="color" value="#666666"/>
         <style name="font-size" value="9pt"/>
      </number>
      <heading>
         <style name="font-size" value="10pt"/>
         <style name="font-weight" value="bold"/>
         <style name="color" value="#000066"/>
         <style name="border-bottom" value="1px solid #999999"/>
      </heading>
   </stylesheet>
</kbarticle>
```

That template XML is what I tried to use and assign to the new article, but obviously it doesn't look right when the article is viewed, the template content is there along with the content I added, its basically duplicated:
[image: kb article viewed in UI]

I did also see there is a FormatXML attribute on the template, which contains XSL to transform the XML, I tried using this but it produces HTML output that isn't what I want either.  I'm struggling with how to get from the template to the ArticleXML that I need in order to create the new KB article.  Any help with this is much appreciated!